How to add function to InlineKeyboardButton in Python-Telegram-Bot?
I work with python telegram bot version more than 20. I'm trying to make when I choose option 1 it would send a message with my function and when i choose for example option 2 it would return other function.
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, Update
from telegram.ext import 

async def start_command(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
keyboard = [
[
InlineKeyboardButton("Option 1", callback_data="1"),
InlineKeyboardButton("Option 2", callback_data="2"),
],
[InlineKeyboardButton("Option 3", callback_data="3"),]
]

    reply_markup1 = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    await update.message.reply_text('Hello!')
    await update.message.reply_text('Choose one of options',reply_markup=reply_markup1)

async def help_command(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
await update.message.reply_text("how can i help you")

async def button(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
query = update.callback_query
await query.answer()
await query.edit_message_text(text=f'Selected option: {query.data}')
if query.data == "1":
    await query.message.reply_text(help_command)

It would look something like this in telegram:

Hello!


Choose one of options


(option 1)(option 2)
(     option 3     )


[i select option 1]


how can i help you

Here's what error i get:
telegram.error.NetworkError: Unknown error in HTTP implementation: TypeError('Object of type function is not JSON serializable')

I don't remeber what i tried but i also got this error before:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reply_text'

I saw a similar question but there is still no answer
